# Solving $x^3+y^3=x^2y^2+1$ in non-negative integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I wanted to solve $x^3+y^3=x^2y^2+1$ in non-negative integers.

First I set $a=x+y$ and $b=xy$ to get $b^2+3ab+1=a^3$. View as a quadratic in $b$, the discriminant = $4a^3+9a^2-4$, which needs to be a perfect square.

Secondly, rearranging the quadratic in $b$ we get $4a^3+9a^2-4=(2b+3a)^2$.

So the discriminant is always a perfect square. Therefore we have (quadratic formula):

$b=\frac{-3a\pm (2b+3b)}{2}$ so $b\in \{b,-\frac{3a}{2}\}$.

Since we want $a,b\ge 0$, the only possibility is $a=b=0$ to give $x=y=0$.

This is the unique solution.

Note: I wasn't sure if it works, I never tried this way before.

Thanks!

Comment: $b\in\{b,\ldots\}$ does not look like much of a success

Comment: Note: $1^3+1^3 = 1^2\times1^2 +1$

Comment: Your solution $x=y=0$ is not a solution, try putting it in the equation and see how it gives $0=1$. The actual integer solutions are $x=1,y=0$ and $x=y=1$

Comment: In the equation, the number of solutions of course.  The equation can only be solved is:  $z^3+x^3=x^2y^2+1$

Comment: *Is this allowed*? is not a good title; it gives no clue to what the question is. [Choose better titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: Sigh. What is the **source** of this problem? at the $x^2 - p y^2 = 2$ you said you were in high school; your Hard Diophantine from three hours ago turned out to be a transplant from Art of Problem Solving.

Comment: $$\color{blue}{ w^2 = 4 a^3 + 9 a^2 - 4 }   $$ is an elliptic curve, the set of integer points is finite, for most such curves there is no elementary way to find all of them and prove that you have all.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve

Answer (score 2):

Introducing the variables $a$ and $b$ leads to the condition
$$4a^3+9a^2-4=(2b+3a)^2\ ,$$
which implies that
$$4a^3+9a^2-4$$
has to be a perfect square. A quick computer search ($|a|\leq 10^6$) produced  the solutions
$$a=-2,\quad-1,\quad1,\quad 2,\quad 25\ .$$
This should be some material to work with.

(The logic in the second half of your argument is circular.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following fact has been violated:-

In the quadratic equation, f(X) = 0, its discriminant ($\triangle$) should be free from X.

It is alright to have $\triangle = 4a^3 + 9a^2 – 4$, but rewriting it as $(2b + 3a)^2$ **and** use it to solve f(b) = 0 is not allowable.

Comment: It's of interest *why* it doesn't work, though ... If you find a solution some other way, these expressions should still hold,... I'd think the only risk here is that you'd wind up trying to solve the original quadratic again - or wind up with an identity - So, the latter is the case with "b can be b",  and the 'other' root for b is a spurious solution with the 'wrong' sign of the squared quantity ( giving only a zero solution, which doesn't hold in the original). So "b can be b" tells us other solutions could exist, but can't be found this way.

Comment: @greggo The story starts from the derivation of the formula of solving x from px^2 + qx + r = 0. We found x = –q…⊿… . In which, ⊿ = q^2 – 4pr (as well as the whole expression) is free from x. Looking at it from another angle, if ⊿ is a function of x, then the “solution” becomes x = –q…x… . That is, it is now in the ‘x is function of x’ state. The good way to think of it is the final solution has not been obtained yet. The bad way to look at it is “going round and round”.

Comment: Yes, but *some* x = f(x) can still be solved for x. This, however, is a case where you wind up with x=x. I was just saying, it's good to know why it's a not a valid approach, and what will happen if you go ahead and take it anyway. The 'other' solution for b - which shows up, I believe, due to an inapplicable root of the determinant - has distracted OP from this, I think. One could argue that the critical *logic* error (as opposed to *method* error) in the OP is "this is the unique solution", which disregards that b=b represents a valid branch and still allows all possible (a,b).

Comment: @greggo Agreed. In short, still "go ahead and take it anyway" is somewhat like trying to re-invent the wheel.